# Как сформулировать тезис и зачин в итоговом сочинении?

Tags: егэ, обучение, литературоведение

Пишу сочинение-рассуждение по пьесе А. Н. Островского "Гроза" в формате итогового сочинения по теме: "Проблема трагической любви на примере образа Катерины".

Как сформулировать тезис и зачин? В чем различие между ними?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачин - это вступление, Ваши рассуждения о проблеме любви. Кто когда писал на эту тему? Почему в произведениях Островского нет счастливой любви, только трагическая?

Тезис - ответ на проблемный вопрос, Ваше авторское мнение, которое Вы потом будете доказывать примерами из текста. Почему трагична любовь героини? Что стало причиной её драмы?