# О термине «зачин» в школьных сочинениях

Tags: выбор-слов, терминология, литературоведение

Почему в школе используется **термин «зачин» вместо слова «вступление»?**  В словарях нет такого значения, но какая-то причина для этого  должна быть.

Примечание. Школьники даже не всегда его понимают, если спрашивают, чем зачин отличается от тезиса.

Из словаря Кузнецова

**ЗАЧИН**,  м. 1. Устар. Начало, почин. * Зачин дело красит (Посл.). 2. Лит. Традиционное начало, характерное для произведений фольклора (былины, песни, сказки).

Из словаря Ефремовой

**ЗАЧИН**, 1. Традиционное начало сказки, былины, песни. 2. разг. Начало, почин

По вопросу  [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462861/Как-сформулировать-тезис-и-зачин-в-итоговом-сочинении](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462861/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%81-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Comment: В Сети встречается, причем в качестве синонима для "вступления", например: https://blog.tutoronline.ru/ustnoe-vyskazyvanie-zachin   Наверное, им синонимов не хватает, или еще чего-нибудь не хватает.

Comment: В сочинениях тоже встречается, например: https://www.sites.google.com/site/personalnyjsajtnikulinojtg/ucasimsa/gotovimsa-k-ege-1/socinenie-rassuzdenie-po-procitannomu-tekstu/tipy-zacinov-i-zaklucenij   также: https://infourok.ru/podgotovka-k-sochineniyu-v-ege-po-russkomu-yaziku-2427963.html

Comment: Еще здесь: https://studopedia.ru/14_45104_tipi-zachinov.html

Answer (score 1):

Это как раз не в школе, это репетиторы, работающие в вузах, употребляют этот термин. В школе только "вступление". Видимо, десятиклассник, который готовится самостоятельно к ЕГЭ по сайтам Интернета, наткнулся на такой термин и стал в ступор, спрашивает, что это такое. Есть такой термин и вот на этом сайте, явно не школьном: https://ist.na5bal.ru/doc/8398/index.html

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение.